# Why won't the find_all() function from beautifulsoup4 not grab all <h3> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import pprint as pp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
headers = {
     'User-Agent': 'some_name',
        'From': 'some_email'
}
URL = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/'
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
page_html = page.content

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

print(page_soup.find_all('h3'))


print(page.status_code)
page.close()
```

This is my first time using beautifulsoup and I'm trying to learn how to use it. For some reason when I try to grab the  tags it only grabs the first 8 and then stops. I don't understand how I can get it to grab every tag. I've tried specifying the class but, that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To get all links you can use *old* version of Reddit.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


URL = 'https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',}
page_soup = soup(requests.get(URL, headers = headers).content, "html.parser")

for p in page_soup.select('p.title'):
    print(p.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
What Are Your Moves Tomorrow, June 15, 2020 Daily Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
They are getting ready for Monday. Meme ( v.redd.it )
Chill Session incoming this week Meme ( v.redd.it )
Just a bull huntin for some calls Meme ( v.redd.it )
this does not feel bullish Meme ( i.imgur.com )
I'm from the past. Here's what's going to happen. Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
Bulls tread lightly we're in for a gong show Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
I've been workin' on this meme for a while...It's about Friendship Meme ( v.redd.it )
I've got a great idea to fix my portfolio ( sound on ) OC Meme ( v.redd.it )
Welcome to the Kang Gang OC Meme ( i.redd.it )
DDDD - Retail Investors, Bankruptcies, Dark Pools and Beauty Contests OC DD ( self.wallstreetbets )
We made WSJ lol Discussion ( wsj.com )
The Great Gay Bear Trade Fundamentals ( self.wallstreetbets )
US Important news this week (est) Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
How George Floyd Cured COVID (and why we're never locking down again) DD ( self.wallstreetbets )
The Kang Gang Manifesto - A 2-month journey from $120k to $210k Gain ( self.wallstreetbets )
The unofficial wallstreetbets alignment chart Meme ( i.redd.it )
Bigly expirations this Friday, watch out Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
Amazon Set to Face Antitrust Charges in European Union Stocks ( nytimes.com )
The Convergence of Retardation and Philanthropy......Autists United, Inc. DD ( self.wallstreetbets )
Ending the Kangaroo Market (Sound On) Meme ( v.redd.it )
Hey Dontsweatit32 - hold my beer and take a ban Options ( i.redd.it )
Hewooo Retards, Carebear here warning you about the incoming Monday's rug pull. DD ( self.wallstreetbets )
DGLY Sympathy Plays Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
Is Apple going going to another new All Time High??? Discussion ( self.wallstreetbets )
I'm all in on spce YOLO ( self.wallstreetbets )
```

---

EDIT: If you want to use new version, you can try this example (it needs parsing JavaScript with `re`/`json` module):

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


URL = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',}
page_soup = soup(requests.get(URL, headers = headers).content, "html.parser")

txt = page_soup.select_one('script#data').contents[0]

data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\.___r = (.*?});', txt).group(1))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for v in data['posts']['models'].values():
    print(v['title'])
```

Prints:

```
What Are Your Moves Tomorrow, June 15, 2020
They are getting ready for Monday.
Chill Session incoming this week
Just a bull huntin for some calls
this does not feel bullish
I'm from the past. Here's what's going to happen.
Bulls tread lightly we're in for a gong show
I've been workin' on this meme for a while...It's about Friendship
DDDD - Retail Investors, Bankruptcies, Dark Pools and Beauty Contests
I've got a great idea to fix my portfolio ( sound on )
Welcome to the Kang Gang
We made WSJ lol
The Great Gay Bear Trade
US Important news this week (est)
How George Floyd Cured COVID (and why we're never locking down again)
The Kang Gang Manifesto - A 2-month journey from $120k to $210k
The unofficial wallstreetbets alignment chart
Bigly expirations this Friday, watch out
Amazon Set to Face Antitrust Charges in European Union
The Convergence of Retardation and Philanthropy......Autists United, Inc.
Ending the Kangaroo Market (Sound On)
Hey Dontsweatit32 - hold my beer and take a ban
Hewooo Retards, Carebear here warning you about the incoming Monday's rug pull.
We did it again. The second wave is coming soon and I am all in with PUTs in everything!
I'm all in on spce
DGLY Sympathy Plays
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a reason why it won't work with the current version of reddit?

Comment: @avaldez I added to my answer parsing the standard version of reddit too (see my edit). The problem with standard version is that is using JavaScript heavily and BeautifulSoup doesn't execute JavaScript.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm new to HTML are there any hints to noticing when a page might be using java script? and if I wanna keep scraping data from old Reddit and the following pages how would you look to do that since the links don't seem to follow a pattern.

Comment: @avaldez You can always do `print(soup)` and see, if the required content is there. If not, there's great chance the page uses JavaScript to inject the content dynamically. For the second question: You can always get all links from old version of Reddit (with `.select()` or `.find_all()` functions) and follow the links.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this longer then I wanted to be and this helps a ton!